# Not able to unlock the AEM page in AEM6.2 for custom template

Tags: aem

I am not able to unlock the page in touch UI editor. Created simple template and page component. There is no code inside the jsp . I am able to lock the page but when trying to unlock page, getting JS in console(please see attached scree shot). It is working fine with geometric template,

Step to produce.
create simple template and component as below
[image: tempalte1]

[image: template 2]

[image]

create a page out of this template
open the in touch ui mode.

lock the page

Now try to unlock the below. see the console by pressing f12. below error is displaying.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to see first the error.log located in your environment, for instance: `AUTHOR_INSTANCE_DIR/crx-quickstart/logs/error.log`.

This may provide more information about the issue. You should validate that you are logged in as an `admin` or at least you are the owner of lock, you can do this by going to the CRXDE Lite, and in the `jcr:content` node of your page you have to see `jcr:lockOwner` property with your username.